# wordpress images staggered

Tags: image, wordpress, html

Wordpress noob alert! In my home page's HTML editor, I've added a div that is the footer. Loaded in this  is a row of logo images that are supposed to sitting a straight line - however, they display staggered vertically. The top left logo (Ocean Basket) sits correctly, the next one has too much padding / margin, the next even more and then next logo even more and so on. I've set the padding and margin to 0 in the css, floated the images left - I cannot understand why this is happening! Any ideas anybody?
test site at http://inexshopfitting.co.za/

Answer (score 1):

try adding `display: block;` to the images and get rid of the `<br>` in between.

(for example by adding `#home_logostrip_box br{ display:none; }` to your themes css file)

That should do it.

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for your suggestions! I never inserted any line breaks after the images but after your suggestion I went and viewed source and in there I see that there are <br />'s after the images. They are not there in the HTML in the WP editor - what to do? How do I get them out? Thank you!!!

Comment: Found the answer yay! On line 248 of wp-includes/formatting.php,
change "<br />\n" to "" - to remove any pesky unwanted line breaks. Hope it doesn't break anything!!!

Comment: i edited to answer sugesting another solution (which does not involve hacking into the core ;)

Comment: I am very nervous about hacking into the core, let me be honest :D I wouldn't have suggested that, especially since i'm such a noob at wordpress but didn't know how else to get rid of the line breaks!

Answer (score 0):

I had 5 images floated next to each other (20% each) and it worked fine in HTML, but not when site was converted to Wordpress; the images where floated but they 'stairstepped/staggered'. Like mentioned before, there are bracketed 'br' elements between each image---inserted by Wordpress. I fixed by adding to my images' container class, .classname br { display: none }. It worked perfectly.